# Abelian subcategory generated by a full subcategory.

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

If $\mathcal{C}$ is a full subcategory of an abelian category $\mathcal{C}'$ to what extent does the abelian subcategory generated by $\mathcal{C}$ depend on the ambient category $\mathcal{C}'$?

Specifically I have the following question in mind:  Suppose I have a category $\mathcal{C}$ which embeds as a full subcategory in two abelian categories $\mathcal{C}'$, $\mathcal{C}''$. Under what circumstances can I conclude that the abelian categories generated by $\mathcal{C}$ are equivalent?

Answer (score 4):

It can depend a lot. For a very specific example, let $C$ consist of a single object with endomorphism ring $\mathbb{Z}$. $C$ embeds into two familiar abelian categories: the category $\text{Ab}$ of abelian groups, and the category $\text{Ab}^{op}$, which by Pontryagin duality can be thought of as the category of compact Hausdorff abelian groups. In the first case, the abelian subcategory generated by $C$ is the category of finitely generated abelian groups, while in the second case it is the opposite, which by Pontryagin duality can be thought of as the category of compact abelian Lie groups.

These two categories are not equivalent. For example, the category of finitely generated abelian groups admits a generator (namely $\mathbb{Z}$) but does not admit a cogenerator, and hence its opposite admits a cogenerator but does not admit a generator.

More generally, if $C$ consists of a single object with endomorphism ring $R$, then $C$ embeds as a full subcategory of any category of modules such that some module has endomorphism ring $R$, *and* as a full subcategory of the *opposite* of any category of modules such that some module has endomorphism ring $R^{op}$.  The problem with your hypotheses is that you have no control over the relationship between limits and colimits in $C'$ and limits and colimits in $C''$. If you'd only asked for limits or for colimits then I think there would at least be a universal answer, but here I think there is no "free abelian category" functor.

Comment: I think there _is_ a free abelian category. Certainly, the forgetful functor from the category of small abelian categories _with chosen zero objects, biproducts, kernels, and cokernels_  and functors that _strictly_ preserve this structure to the category of small categories (or even small $\mathbf{Ab}$-categories) has a left adjoint; but it's not so clear to me whether you can do the same thing with the obvious 2-categories.

Comment: Great, thanks for the example and the insight. I was pretty sure this would not be true in this generality, however I'm still interested in the "under what circumstances"  part of the question though. For example some additional criteria on $\mathcal{C}$ or how it sits inside the larger categories that would allow us to conclude this.

Comment: @Zhen: the strict version is not clear to me (and of course I want the 2-categorical version). Do you know a construction?

Comment: @Nate: what kind of applications do you have in mind?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I don't have an explicit construction, but it is clear because the "strict" abelian categories I described are models for an essentially algebraic theory. The existence of the left adjoint follows from general principles, or if you like, the accessible adjoint functor theorem.

Comment: Hmmm. Actually, come to think of it, the 2-category of small abelian categories and exact functors to the 2-category of small categories has  2-colimits for filtered diagrams, 2-cotensors, small products, inserters, and equifiers, and these are all preserved by the forgetful 2-functor to the 2-category of small categories (or small $\mathbf{Ab}$-categories), so the only obstruction to the existence of a left 2-adjoint should be local presentability...

Comment: @Zhen: this is still not clear to me. How does an essentially algebraic theory handle kernels, cokernels, and the condition that every monomorphism and epimorphism is regular? Why does the category of "strictly abelian" categories and "strictly exact" functors have limits, and why does the forgetful functor preserve these limits?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan For kernels, we introduce a map $\operatorname{ker} : \operatorname{mor} \mathcal{C} \to \operatorname{mor} \mathcal{C}$ and a partially defined map $c_\mathrm{ker} : \operatorname{mor} \mathcal{C} \times \operatorname{mor} \mathcal{C} \to \operatorname{mor} \mathcal{C}$ such that $c_\mathrm{ker} (g, f)$ is defined if and only if $\operatorname{codom} f = \operatorname{dom} g$ and $g \circ f = 0$, in which case $\operatorname{dom} c_\mathrm{ker} (g, f) = \operatorname{dom} f$ and $\operatorname{codom} c_\mathrm{ker} (g, f) = \operatorname{dom} \ker f$ etc.

Comment: The fact that every monomorphism and epimorphism is normal is equivalent to $\operatorname{coker} \ker \cong \ker \operatorname{coker}$, which can be handled by defining an inverse to the canonical comparison $\operatorname{coker} \ker \to \ker \operatorname{coker}$. As for the existence and preservation of limits, that is automatic when we have an essentially algebraic theory.

Comment: It now occurs to me that free "strict" abelian categories are automatically free abelian categories as well: you can always turn any abelian category into a strict one, and any "strictly" exact functor is in particular exact, so every functor out of the generating subcategory extends to an exact functor.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: The most immediate application I had in mind is the following:  I have two algebras which are not Morita equivalent, but both appear to have a rather large (and interesting) common abelian subcategory (which isn't coming from Morita equivalent quotient algebras in any obvious way) and I was trying to show this is indeed the case.  What I can definitely find is two full subcategories which generate these abelian categories which are equivalent, and I was hoping to extend the equivalence.

Comment: @Nate: how big are these full subcategories? Are they closed under any limits or colimits? (Being closed under finite direct sums doesn't help.)

Comment: Hmm...  The main nice property these full subcategories have is that they are closed under taking direct summands.  Beyond that, no other nice closure properties jump out at me.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Apparently free abelian categories were constructed explicitly by Freyd. See also [this paper](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.hha/1139841219).